# perform operation based on a block of rows

Tags: excel

I have a excel table and I would like to compute values based on a set of rows.
Visually it's something like:

```
block_1
...
block_n

Mblock
```

where each block has say 20 lines. The formulas I want to compute depend on `Mblock`. For the first block this works fine but when I drag passed the first block excel uses the lines that follow `Mblock` where I would like it to use again the first line in `Mlbock` and so on.

How can this be done in excel?

Comment: Rather than this apparently made us sample set, let's for now assume your data blocks are 5-6 rowss deep.  Please put together and post a couple of full sets of data.... let us see the blocks, the mblocks, AND the "results" of the formula you'd like to create, presumably in the next column, yes?  Show us a fully mocked up sample and I'm sure we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each block is 20 lines, Mblock is a named range for Mblock and you just want to return the relative Mblock value you could do this:

```
=INDEX(Mblock, ROW() - ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/20)*20)
```

Which should return the nth item in Mblock when called from n row in each 20 row block.

Answer (score 1):

If you place a `$` before the row or column reference it will make it absolute. If you need to stop both the row and column from changing then you need to put the `$` twice, e.g. `$A$1`.

EDIT:

Why not lay out your blocks horizontally instead?

```
Mblock block_1 ... blockn
```

Then you can refer to the absolute column containing Mblock but the row will vary appropriately.

Comment: It sounds like skeept wants the 20 rows to cycle and return the relative item in Mblock.  I don't think this is what is needed.